# Tuning queries and indexes using index analysis tool

Tags: index, database-tuning, sybase

I've been pointed to this script from several places which apparently helps with designing indexes in Microsoft SQL Server: http://indexanalysis.codeplex.com/

The problem is I'm using Sybase ASA 11, which seems to use a slightly different implementation of T-SQL than the one used by MS. I'm getting all sorts of errors when I try to run the script.

I know enough about database tuning to tell where to put indexes, and that's about it. I'm a programmer, so I don't know about it as much as I'd like to.

My question is: Is there anything similar to this tool for Sybase? I need to know where to put indexes without going to each and every query (if I can avoid it).

Comment: Hi Dan, welcome to [dba.se]. Are you asking if there is an equivalent index analysis tool for sybase?

Comment: @Dan The tool/script you've linked too is possibly too deep a level of analysis for what you're looking for. More suitable would be the Sybase equivalent of SQL Servers [Database Tuning Advisor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494.aspx), if such a tool exists. Might be worth editing your question to reflect this if it's the case.

Comment: Updated the question per your requests. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Sybase 3rd party tools are sparse unless you spend money it seems.

The usual vendor suspects have Sybase offerings:

- Embarcadero's [DB PowerStudio for Sybase ASE](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/db-powerstudio-for-sybase) which claims to have index analysis (+ lots of other stuff)
- [Quest have some tools](http://www.quest.com/sybase/) but not sure what you would be best